# Missing objects in response from web service - c#

Tags: c#

I have big problem.
This is autogenerated method in reference.cs

```
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute("SecurityValue")]
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute("MessageHeaderValue")]
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
    [return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("TestResponse", Namespace="http:/test/Services")]
    public TestResponse testRequest([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("TestRequest", Namespace="http://Test.com/TestServices")] TestRequestTestRequest1) {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("TestRequest", new object[] {
                    TestRequest1});
        return ((TestResponse)(results[0]));
```

This is arrayitem (also auto-generated):

```
/// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.18047")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.foo.com")]
    public partial class FieldListType {

        private MapTypeEntry[] mapField;

        private string nameField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Entry", typeof(MapTypeEntry), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=false)]
        public MapTypeEntry[] Map {
            get {
                return this.mapField;
            }
            set {
                this.mapField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string Name {
            get {
                return this.nameField;
            }
            set {
                this.nameField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.18047")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://www.foo.com")]
    public partial class MapTypeEntry {

        private string keyField;

        private string valueField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string Key {
            get {
                return this.keyField;
            }
            set {
                this.keyField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string Value {
            get {
                return this.valueField;
            }
            set {
                this.valueField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem is missing objects in Map array. I've catch response from web response via Fiddler. In response there is three Map object in array.
But in my TestResponse in code I've found only one (last attempt) object.
I tried few things, but I'm still not found good solution.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that `XML` *tags* are accessed with same casting at both ends. If the casting is different, then the value won't be read.

Comment: This is snippet from Fiddler:

`<FieldList Name="FirstObject">
     <Map>
      <Entry Key="OneKey" Value="1  "/>
      <Entry Key="TwoKey" Value="C  "/>
      <Entry Key="ThreeKey" Value="1"/>
     </Map>
     <Map>
     <Entry Key="OneKey" Value="123"/>
      <Entry Key="TwoKey" Value="DDD"/>
      <Entry Key="ThreeKey" Value="123123"/>
     </Map>
    </FieldList>`

In array there is only last Map object with OneKey = 123.

Comment: You need to check the xml returned by your service. it returns a string which contains a `XML`

Comment: I've checked in Fiddler what is returned by service. There is all what I want to.

Comment: You also check, all message are sending back from your webservice. Then, call your webservice manually and check its response. If all data is there, then your webservice reference is outdated; Update it by right-clicking your webservice reference and choose `Update'

Comment: I did it too. I called web service using my response using soapUI.

Comment: If your `data` **don't came back**, your problem is related to webservice code, Also, check if all return types are **public** as it is mandatory for `serialization`.

Comment: Data come back in fiddler and soapUI. What's more. When I change return type from response to object[] and manually deserialize to xmlNodeList - all data are all right. I have no idea what I can do more.

Comment: Then check with the the **ordering** of the `XML tags` in the `message`. If it so, then the _parameter values_ will be **disappear** during `transmission` because the sending part order the tags differently than what it will be defined in the schema